# where to find TPC-C queries

Tags: sql-server

I've been looking around for specific TPC-C queries but haven't found good sources. Does anyone have a pointer?

As I'm aware of, TPC-H only has 22 queries which could be easily found here http://www.qdpma.com/tpch/TPCH100_Query_plans.html and here https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-testbench/tree/hive14/sample-queries-tpch. I was wondering if it's the same case for TPC-C benchmark. Does it also have a fixed number of distinct queries and where could I find them? I just have a specific task in which I need to measure the performance of each query and I thought both TPC-H and TPC-C queries are good references. Thanks!

Comment: HammerDB contains both benchmarks.

Comment: I know that I could run tpch and tpcc benchmarks using HammerDB, but I wasn't able to see the exact queries that the benchmarks use. Specifically, all the distinct queries that are used like listed as the TPCH examples.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to run a trace or extended event session to capture that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TPC-C contains a fixed number of *transactions*, not queries. They are described in Clause 2 of http://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/pdf/tpc-c_v5.11.0.pdf. Sample implementations including SQL are in Appendix A.